# Image zoom on hover, keep image centred

Tags: html, css, sass

```css
.featured-items__image-container {
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 370px;
}

.featured-items__item-image {
    @include animate(all, 500ms);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.featured-items__item-image:hover {
    height: 120%;
    width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-items__image-container">
    <img class="featured-items__item-image" src="https://unsplash.it/370/250"/>
</div>
```

So on hover, the I'm adding 20% to both the width and the height. Which works perfectly. But The image isn't centred and that's what I'm struggling with. So on zoom the image just sort of "grows" to the right. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.featured-items__image-container {
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 370px;
}

.featured-items__item-image {
    @include animate(all, 500ms);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.featured-items__item-image:hover {
    height: 120%;
    width: 120%;
    margin-left:-10%;
    margin-top:-10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-items__image-container">
    <img class="featured-items__item-image" src="https://unsplash.it/370/250"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also apply relative positioning to the image and set the left, top to -10%, -10% respectively, this is will shift the image from where it is supposed to be and achieve the desired output.

```
.featured-items__item-image:hover {
    height: 120%;
    width: 120%;
    position:relative;
    left:-10%;
    top:-10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the height, it might be easier to use 'scale' in the transform property, which automatically centres the zooming.

```
.featured-items__image-container {
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 370px;
}

.featured-items__item-image {
    @include animate(all, 500ms);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.featured-items__item-image:hover {
   transform: scale(1.2)
}
```